# SQL DataReader giving "string or binary data will be truncated"

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to read a table where under normal circumstances zero rows will be returned. If any rows are returned an error message is shown. I've tested the SQL statement in on SQL Server and it works. However, I'm getting an error in the DataReader. My code is as follows:

```
Using sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cSettings.PrimaryConnectionString)
     Dim sSQLc As String = "SELECT * FROM UnitHistory " _
                            + "WHERE Unit=" + iUnitID.ToString + " " _
                            + "AND StartDate<='" + returnSQLDateString(dAdmissionDateTime) + "' " _
                            + "AND (EndDate IS NULL OR " _
                            + "EndDate>'" + returnSQLDateString(dAdmissionDateTime) + "') " _
                            + "AND IsAmended IS NULL AND IsReversed IS NULL"
     Using sqlCMD As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sSQLc, sqlConn)
         Using sqlR As SqlDataReader = sqlCMD.ExecuteReader ' <--- (The error is raised at this line)
             If sqlR.HasRows Then
                 ' if rows were returned then there was someone in the unit
                 ' we're trying to admit to.
                 MsgBox("There is an admission already in this unit for this admission date")
                 Exit Sub
             End If
         End Using
     End Using
End Using
```

A sample SQL Statement which this generates is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM UnitHistory 
WHERE Unit=1 
AND StartDate<='2019-07-14 20:55' 
AND (EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate>'2019-07-14 20:55') 
AND IsAmended IS NULL 
AND IsReversed IS NULL
```

The columns in question (as in the SQL Statement) are int/DateTime/DateTime/Bit/Bit

I can't see why this is causing the error to be raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're only using the query to test if there is anything present, perhaps it would make more sense to use a count of the relevant rows.

The `using` statements can be combined into one, which is sometimes neater. Also, you should always use SQL parameters for SQL queries: that prevents problems with dates, names with apostrophes, and SQL injection attacks - and the query is easier to read.

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM UnitHistory 
WHERE Unit = @unit
AND StartDate <= @startDate
AND (EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate > @endDate) 
AND IsAmended IS NULL 
AND IsReversed IS NULL"

Using sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cSettings.PrimaryConnectionString),
        cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@unit", SqlDbType.Int).Value = iUnitID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dAdmissionDateTime
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dAdmissionDateTime

    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim admissionCount = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

    If admissionCount > 0 Then
        ' if rows were returned then there was someone in the unit
        ' we're trying to admit to.
        MsgBox("There is an admission already in this unit for this admission date.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Using
```

(If your copy of Visual Studio doesn't like the multi-line string for `sql`, just put it all on one line.)

Comment: Hi Andrew, The issue turned out to be something that I was aware of while I was writing the code but didn't attach sufficient significance to it:

Comment: The issue turned out 2 b something that I was aware of while I was writing the code but didn't attach sufficient significance 2 it: The conn was created earlier in code (+ so 1-lining it wasn't possible - but I didn't know u could do that). However, as this SR is a write SR I'd added a transaction to the conn. Not including this read in the transaction was causing the error. I only realised this by creating a new conn (all in one line) as a last resort. Re Parameters, I always use them for writes. Will start using for reads. Thanks

Comment: I'm unsure of the etiquette here. Both guys answered the question but the solution lay elsewhere (i.e. my stupidity). However, I felt I learned another new thing from Andrew's answer. If my approach is in error, please let me know.

Comment: @Seamus The guidance is to accept an answer which helped, so I suppose my one counts, even if it wasn't for the actual question.

Comment: I am not sure if this would work here but Sql Server has an If Exists. Depending on the size of the table this could return somewhat faster.

Answer (score 0):

I went to SQL Management studio and tried a similar query on one of my tables and it quickly pointed out the problem.  It wanted additional parentheses.

```
    Using sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cSettings.PrimaryConnectionString)
     Dim sSQLc As String = "SELECT * FROM UnitHistory " _
                            + "WHERE (Unit=" + iUnitID.ToString + ") " _
                            + "AND (StartDate<='" + returnSQLDateString(dAdmissionDateTime) + "') " _
                            + "AND ((EndDate IS NULL) OR " _
                            + "(EndDate>'" + returnSQLDateString(dAdmissionDateTime) + "')) " _
                            + "AND (IsAmended IS NULL) AND (IsReversed IS NULL)"
     Using sqlCMD As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sSQLc, sqlConn)
         Using sqlR As SqlDataReader = sqlCMD.ExecuteReader ' <--- (The error is raised at this line)
             If sqlR.HasRows Then
                 ' if rows were returned then there was someone in the unit
                 ' we're trying to admit to.
                 MsgBox("There is an admission already in this unit for this admission date")
                 Exit Sub
             End If
         End Using
     End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for replying. Unfortunately, adding the brackets didn't sort the problem out. This issue turned out (as they sometimes do) to be due to an oversight on my part which I'll detail below.