# vb.net insert statement : sql Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert data from vb.net into a SQL Server database.

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[gsb_dtab]
(
    [gsb_sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [gsb_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [gsb_quality] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [gsb_stype] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [gsb_taka] [int] NULL
)
```

VB.NET code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO gsb_dtab (gsb_date, gsb_quality, gsb_taka) 
                   VALUES('" + out_date + "','" + se_qcombo.Text + "','" + txt_taka.Text + "');"
```

The values I want to store are :

- out_date = 2020-05-03
- se_qcombo = Ranial
- txt_taka = 48

but SQL Server throws an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

The error happens in `txt_taka` insert; when I ignore `txt_taka`, then data is inserted successfully.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and vb.net 2010

Please help - what can I do ?

Comment: Use SQL parameters instead of concatenating the values in as strings and then it will work properly.

Comment: sorry  one more thing  [gsb_stype] [nchar](1) NOT NULL  not exist in table

Comment: You could work from this answer: [SQL DataReader giving “string or binary data will be truncated”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246636/1115360).

Comment: You have specified that `gsb_stype` cannot be `null` but you're not providing a value for that column when you insert.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 (and R2) have been completely unsupported for almost a year now. Yu should really be looking at upgrade paths, along with fixing all the injection issues you have.

Comment: @Mp594, here is more information about [why parameters are a best practice](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).

Comment: @DanGuzman I hadn't seen that blog post of yours before; very interesting :) You will know better than I, but weren't parameters meant to be the way of adding values back when SQL was invented, and it was only an unfortunate possibility to add them inline?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I think the TDS protocol (MSSQL and Sybase) has always supported parameters but I can't say to what extent the many app languages and APIs have used them over the years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not concatenate strings to build `.CommandText`. You will be open to sql injection and you `.CommandText` is much harder to read and maintain.

The `Using...End Using` block ensures that you connection and command are closed and disposed even it there is an error.

```
Private Sub InsertSomething(out_date As Date)
    Dim sqlString = "INSERT INTO gsb_dtab (gsb_date, gsb_quality, gsb_taka) 
               VALUES(@Date, @seq, @taka);"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlString, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = out_date
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@seq", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = se_qcombo.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@taka", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txt_taka.Text)
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Put strings in apostrophes, but don't do it with numbers. The format of date values should be "'yyyy-MM-dd'" or 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'. Also use "&" for string concatenation, because "+" could lead to weird errors. And the semicolon at the end isn't needed. So the code could look like:

```
Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO gsb_dtab (gsb_date, gsb_quality, gsb_taka) " &
    "VALUES(" & Strings.Format(out_date, "\'yyyy-MM-dd\'") &
    ", '" & se_qcombo.Text & "', " & txt_taka.Text & ")"

cmd.CommandText = SQL
```

Comment: Please don't encourage people to concatenate strings to build .CommandText. You are risking sql injection.

Answer (score -2):

Please use below code.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO gsb_dtab (gsb_date, gsb_quality, gsb_taka) 
               VALUES('" + out_date + "','" + se_qcombo.Text + "','" + Convert.toInt32(txt_taka.Text) + "');"
```

you need to convert the int value.